# Is there a way to partially match a variadic template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

I currently have a system to "connect" `signal`s to functions. This `signal` is a variadic template that has as template parameters the arguments of the functions it can `connect` to.

In the current implementation, I obviously cannot connect to functions whose arguments aren't exactly the same (or those that can be converted to) as the `signal`'s parameters. Now, as I'm trying to mimic Qt's `signal`/`slot`/`connect`, I'd also like to connect a `signal` of `N` parameters to a `slot` of `M<N` parameters, which is perfectly well-defined (i.e. ignore the `>M` parameters of the signal and just pass the first M to the connected function). For an example of the code I have in its most simplistic form, see [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a36abcf3e0b124a9).

So the question is two-fold:

1. How do I make the `connect` call work for a function `void g(int);`?
2. How do I make the `emit` call work for a function `void g(int);`?

I'm guessing I'll have to make some "magic" parameter pack reducer for both the `slot` and its call function, but I can't see how it all should fit together so it's quite hard to actually start trying to code a solution. I'm OK with a C++17-only solution, if at least Clang/GCC and Visual Studio 2015 can compile it.

The code linked above for completeness:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<typename... ArgTypes>
struct slot
{
    virtual ~slot() = default;

    virtual void call(ArgTypes...) const = 0;
};

template<typename Callable, typename... ArgTypes>
struct callable_slot : slot<ArgTypes...>
{
    callable_slot(Callable callable) : callable(callable) {}

    void call(ArgTypes... args) const override { callable(args...); }

    Callable callable;
};

template<typename... ArgTypes>
struct signal
{
    template<typename Callable>
    void connect(Callable callable)
    {
        slots.emplace_back(std::make_unique<callable_slot<Callable, ArgTypes...>>(callable));
    }

    void emit(ArgTypes... args)
    {
        for(const auto& slot : slots)
        {
            slot->call(args...);
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<slot<ArgTypes...>>> slots;
};

void f(int, char) {}

int main()
{
    signal<int, char> s;
    s.connect(&f);

    s.emit(42, 'c');
}
```

Comment: Note that I would like to keep the strict typechecking of the first `M` parameters in any case, no use in abolishing type safety to do this. On the other hand, if I am forced to work around the `virtual` simplicity of forwarding the function call to the actual callable object and implementing a "impossible fast delegate", I'll consider it, because it seems this type of thing ties me up quite hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class...> struct voider { using type = void; };
template<class... Ts> using voidify = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template<class C, class...Args>
using const_lvalue_call_t = decltype(std::declval<const C&>()(std::declval<Args>()...));

template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
auto pick_from_tuple_impl(T &&, std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
    -> std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>...>;

template<class Tuple, class = std::enable_if_t<(std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value > 0)>>
using drop_last = decltype(pick_from_tuple_impl(std::declval<Tuple>(), 
                        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>()));

template<class C, class ArgsTuple, class = void>
struct try_call
    : try_call<C, drop_last<ArgsTuple>> {};

template<class C, class...Args>
struct try_call<C, std::tuple<Args...>, voidify<const_lvalue_call_t<C, Args...>>> {
    template<class... Ts>
    static void call(const C& c, Args&&... args, Ts&&... /* ignored */) {
        c(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
    }
};
```

Then in `callable_slot`:

```
void call(ArgTypes... args) const override {
     using caller = try_call<Callable, std::tuple<ArgTypes...>>;
     caller::call(callable, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...); 
}
```

---

For member pointer support (this requires SFINAE-friendly `std::result_of`), change `const_lvalue_call_t` to

```
template<class C, class...Args>
using const_lvalue_call_t = std::result_of_t<const C&(Args&&...)>;
```

then change the actual call in `try_call::call` to

```
std::ref(c)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

This is poor man's `std::invoke` for lvalue callables. If you have C++17, just use `std::invoke` directly (and use `std::void_t` instead of `voidify`, though I like the sound of the latter).

Comment: This looks very promising. I suppose I can force the callable_slot to be constructed from functions of less parameters and then I have it. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm it seems like [this solution doesn't handle member function pointers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dbcbf3f1e33c5b4) :(. Let's see if I can coerce it into doing so...

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I got it working: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/565e3061a49f82d4. Still a bit less powerful than the real version, but that shouldn't be hard to get now that the hard part is over.

Comment: All right, I got my real version working with Clang and GCC. Now the only hurdle that remains is VS2015/2017. I'd prefer to keep 2015 working, but if 2017 is what it takes so be it. And then some more SFINAE to improve error messages on bad calls.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want but... with `std::tuple` and `std::make_index_sequence` ...

First of all you need a type traits that give you the number of arguments of a function (or `std::function`)

```
template <typename>
struct numArgs;

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct numArgs<R(*)(Args...)> 
      : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
 { };

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct numArgs<std::function<R(Args...)>>
      : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
 { };
```

Next you have to add a `constexpr` value in `callable_slot` to memorize the number of arguments in the `Callable` function

```
static constexpr std::size_t numA { numArgs<Callable>::value };
```

Then you have to modify the `call()` method to pack the arguments in a `std::tuple<ArgTypes...>` and call another method passing the tuple and an index sequence from 0 to `numA`

```
void call(ArgTypes... args) const override
 { callI(std::make_tuple(args...), std::make_index_sequence<numA>{}); }
```

Last you have to call, in `CallI()`, the `callable()` function with only the first `numA` elements of the tuple of arguments

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
void callI (std::tuple<ArgTypes...> const & t,
            std::index_sequence<Is...> const &) const
 { callable(std::get<Is>(t)...); }
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename>
struct numArgs;

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct numArgs<R(*)(Args...)> 
   : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
 { };

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct numArgs<std::function<R(Args...)>>
   : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
 { };

template <typename ... ArgTypes>
struct slot
 {
   virtual ~slot() = default;

   virtual void call(ArgTypes...) const = 0;
 };

template <typename Callable, typename ... ArgTypes>
struct callable_slot : slot<ArgTypes...>
 {
   static constexpr std::size_t numA { numArgs<Callable>::value };

   callable_slot(Callable callable) : callable(callable)
    { }

   template <std::size_t ... Is>
   void callI (std::tuple<ArgTypes...> const & t,
               std::index_sequence<Is...> const &) const
    { callable(std::get<Is>(t)...); }

   void call(ArgTypes... args) const override
    { callI(std::make_tuple(args...), std::make_index_sequence<numA>{}); }

   Callable callable;
 };

template <typename ... ArgTypes>
struct signal
 {
   template <typename Callable>
   void connect(Callable callable)
    {
      slots.emplace_back(
         std::make_unique<callable_slot<Callable, ArgTypes...>>(callable));
    }

   void emit(ArgTypes... args)
    { for(const auto& slot : slots) slot->call(args...); }

   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<slot<ArgTypes...>>> slots;
 };

void f (int i, char c)
 { std::cout << "--- f(" << i << ", " << c << ")" << std::endl; }

void g (int i)
 { std::cout << "--- g(" << i << ")" << std::endl; }

struct foo
 {
   static void j (int i, char c)
    { std::cout << "--- j(" << i << ", " << c << ")" << std::endl; }

   void k (int i)
    { std::cout << "--- k(" << i << ")" << std::endl; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::function<void(int, char)> h { [](int i, char c)
       { std::cout << "--- h(" << i << ", " << c << ")" << std::endl; }
    };

   std::function<void(int)> i { [](int i)
       { std::cout << "--- i(" << i << ")" << std::endl; }
    };

   using std::placeholders::_1;

   foo foo_obj{};

   std::function<void(int)> k { std::bind(&foo::k, foo_obj, _1) };

   signal<int, char> s;

   s.connect(f);
   s.connect(g);
   s.connect(h);
   s.connect(i);
   s.connect(foo::j);
   s.connect(k);

   s.emit(42, 'c');
 }
```

This example need C++14 because use `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence`.

Substitute both of they and prepare a C++11 compliant solution isn't really difficult.

Comment: This seems limited in the sense I need a lot of extra code to handle lambda's and member functions, or am I wrong about that?

Comment: @rubenvb - A lot of extra code? No, I don't think so. It seems to me that it's enough to add a `numArgs` specialization for `std::function`. The real problem is that a there isn't a real type for lambda functions (any lambda fanction make a type); so you need to wrap they in `std::function`s (that is also useful for not static methods of struct/classes, toghether with `std::bind`); for static methods of struct/classes the code works without problem. Answer modified for lambda and methods (with examples).

Comment: I don't want the overhead of `std::function` nor any `std::bind`-like things. Note the `slot` I have (the complete thing, not this limited example) pretty much behaves as a reseatable `std::function` (reseatable with respect to a member function pointer and the object it is invoked with).

Comment: @rubenvb - I see... well, I don't know how to manage lambda without `std::function`; maybe someone else can solve the problem.